# Magento 2.2.x - How to create customer radio and checkbox button attribute

Tags: magento2, customer

want to show radio button and checkbox in customer registration page and admin panel... I need exactly radio button and checkbox... But most of the friends mentioned in his/her blog on 'input'=>'boollean', it's not fulfilling my requirement.... Can anyone help me to create the custom customer attribute as radio and checkbox?

Comment: If you are trying to add attribute via install/upgrade data script then you can add value for "input" to required type. It could be 'input' => 'image', 'input' => 'text','input' => 'radio', 'input' => 'checkbox' give a try and let me know if it helps..

Comment: 'input' => 'image', 'input' => 'text','input' => 'radio', 'input' => 'checkbox' it's not working

Comment: I had a check and found that 'input'=>'boollean'  is also creating a checkbox but some additional css added by magento team to get customized look. You can overwrite that css for your particular pages in case..

Comment: see the following i think this is exactly what you need 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263675/how-to-set-value-for-radio-button-in-eav-attribute-of-product-type/263682?noredirect=1#comment372624_263682

Answer (score 0):

> Create Extension and your setup file below 
>  here
>   customer=>namespace & Attribute=>Extension name

```
namespace Customer\Attribute\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\Context;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;

class CustomerSetup extends EavSetup {

    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        Context $context,
        CacheInterface $cache,
        CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
        ) {
        $this -> eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent :: __construct($setup, $context, $cache, $attrGroupCollectionFactory);
    } 

    public function installAttributes($customerSetup) {
        $this -> installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup);
        $this -> installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup);
    } 

    public function installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup) {


        $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'dropdown',
            [
            'label' => 'Radio Button',
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 100,
            'sort_order' =>100,
            'visible' =>  true,
            'note' => '',


                        'type' => 'int',
                        'input' => 'select',
                        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',

            ]
            );

        $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'dropdown')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout']) -> save();



        $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'multiple',
            [
            'label' => 'Multiple',
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 100,
            'sort_order' =>100,
            'visible' =>  true,
            'note' => '',


                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'input' => 'multiselect',
                        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',

            ]
            );

        $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'multiple')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout']) -> save();


    } 

    public function installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup) {

    } 

    public function getEavConfig() {
        return $this -> eavConfig;
    } 
}
```